# Not valid UTF8! byte A7 in state 0

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, jetty

I have a pdf printer which I don't know much about. The pdf that is generated has some images inside. The problem is that images that start with character '§' are not visible in the generated pdf because of this Exception:

```
2016-03-01 20:25:30.424 [qtp1181496842-69] WARN  org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio - handle failed 
org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte A7 in state 0
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable.appendByte(Utf8Appendable.java:178) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.util_8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable.append(Utf8Appendable.java:117) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.util_8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpURI.toUtf8String(HttpURI.java:503) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpURI.getPathAndParam(HttpURI.java:687) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getRequestURI(Request.java:1024) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:364) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:419) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:603) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696) ~[org.eclipse.jetty.io_8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53) [org.eclipse.jetty.io_8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608) [org.eclipse.jetty.util_8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543) [org.eclipse.jetty.util_8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]
```

Any idea why this character causes this or how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

> [Jetty 8 is EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html), please upgrade.

That stacktrace is telling you that in the process of reporting an error to the user, it encountered a bad RequestURI that included invalid UTF8 encodings in either the path or the query parameters.

The Request URI you are using is bad/invalid.

If you upgrade to Jetty 9, your error messages and stacktraces should become more clear as to the source of the issue well.